# Can we add variable as a dependencies which is not part of useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, react-context

```
useEffect(()=>{
    history.push("/home")
  },[token, history])
```

i.e Here token is not part of `useEffect` but I want to add it as a dependencies of `useEffect`.
Can I do this? If not then why?

Comment: Yes you can. Any changes to those variables trigger the change on useEffect. They do not have to be in the useEffect.

Comment: Sure, you can add any dependencies you like to a React hook. Did you try it? Is something not working as you'd expect?

Comment: that's the whole point of the dependency array in useEffect...

Comment: @DrewReese It works fine but I thought we should only add variable which should be part of useEffect.

Comment: Nope. Any dependency that changes in the array will trigger a re-render of useEffect. That's its whole job, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> useEffect(()=>{
>   history.push("/home");
> }, [token, history]);
> ```
>
> i.e Here token is not part of useEffect but I want to add it as a
> dependencies of useEffect. Can I do this? If not then why?

Yes, you can include, or omit, any dependencies, or omit the ***entire*** dependency array.

> It works fine but I thought we should only add variable which should
> be part of useEffect.

Take a look at the official docs, [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and [Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect), and note there is no rule or requirement that dependencies can be only values referenced within the hook's callback.

1. Trigger an effect after ***every*** render by not including a dependency array.

   ```
   useEffect(() => console.log('every render'));
   ```
2. Trigger an effect ***only on mounting*** by including an empty dependency array.

   ```
   useEffect(() => console.log('on component mount only'), []);
   ```
3. Trigger an effect ***conditionally*** by including values in the dependency array you want the effect callback to run after update.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log('any time a, b, or c update'); // or d or e
   }, [a, b, c, d, e]);
   ```

React suggests you use the [ESLint Plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) (`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`) to help enforce the Rules of Hooks and makes dependency suggestions. Note though that these are just opinionated suggestions and when including *more* dependencies, or no dependencies (such as mounting effects) that this plugin will warn you. Note also that this is *only a warning* and not an error (a common misconception).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to follow the guidelines given by React documentation, and provide a dependency array properly.

Probably you could do something like the following:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  if (token) {
    history.push("/home")
  }
},[token, history])
```

An easy way to get hints is using the *eslint-plugin-react-hooks* official eslint plugin provided by React, see [documentation here](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin).

Notice also that usually, if you are using some imported stuff, like probably is `history` in your example, that will not change, so it is not necessary to add it to dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can. Any changes to that variable will trigger the useEffect.

Comment: But I have not used token inside my useEffect