# Cookie in react getting expired/clear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

This is code in which i am setting the cookie

```
document.cookie = 'cookie_consent=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT Secure';
```

Below is my code for checking cookie.

```
useEffect(() => {
const cookieValue = (`; ${document?.cookie}`).split('; cookie_consent=').pop().split(';')[0];
if (!cookieValue) {
  console.log("Cookie not avaliable");
}
}, [document?.cookie]);
```

Cookie is getting expired after accepting within few days since i set cookie expiry as 31 dec 9999 etc.

Thank You in advance, Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a cookie to never expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire)

Comment: @PabloSilió its for php and op is looking for JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a side note, set `useEffect` with `document.cookie` as a dependence will not re-run when `document.cookie` change, it only accepts `state` dependencies

Also,

> All the cookies expire as per the cookie specification. So, there is no block of code you can write in JavaScript to set up a cookie that never expires. It is just impossible and is a fact.

> Solution: But you can set up a cookie that expires in JavaScript and pick some very large value as expiry date as specified below:

```js
const expireDate = new Date(2147483647 * 1000).toUTCString();

document.cookie = `cookie_consent=true; expires=${expireDate} Secure`;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118690/19431815 - As per this answer useEffect will re-run on any data change.

Comment: This question or answer doesn't mean that the `useEffect` can be updated if `normal variable` is updated, it means that `useEffect` can be updated with any `state` dependence even if it doesn't use inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: Anyway, if you have set up eslint in your code editor, you will get this warning message if you set `document.cookie` as dependence on `useEffect`. `React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'document.cookie'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'document.cookie' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`

Comment: Thank you , Got it. I will try your changes and let you know if anything occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be immediately that 9999 is too great as a year.

See the following post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328361/maximum-lifetime-of-javascript-cookie#:~:text=The%20max%20value%20is%202,on%20the%20UNIX%20timestamp%20value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328361/maximum-lifetime-of-javascript-cookie#:%7E:text=The%20max%20value%20is%202,on%20the%20UNIX%20timestamp%20value).

Comment: Could add some details and correct formatting.